# Get digits out of text in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, math

How to get digits out of text in JavaScript or jQuery?

Like this one in PHP:

```
<?php
    $a = "2 Apples";
    $b = "3 Peach";
    echo $a + $b // It will print 5! Thanks for this stupid smartness, 2 apples + 3 peaches should be 2 apples and 3 peaches or maybe a nice jam!
?>
```

Now I want to do something like this with JavaScript with/without jQuery.

```
var a = "100$";
var b = "120$";
var ttl = 100 - Math.round( a + b );
```

Even if I used `(a + b * 1)` and also `(a*1) + (b*1)` to see if it turns it to Int, it returned [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse them. [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will drop the **trailing** non-digit characters.

```
var a = parseInt("100$", 10);
var b = parseInt("120$", 10);

var ttl = 100 - Math.round( a + b );

alert(ttl); // alerts -120
```

As @Jeremy said, this will not work for **leading** non-digit characters. Example:

```
alert(parseInt("$100", 10)); // alerts "NaN"
```

Comment: It should be stressed that it only works on trailing characters. "$100" will return NaN.

Comment: @Jeremy: you are correct, but I did say "trailing" - do I need to bold that?

Comment: I was only clarifying for someone reading who may not read into the answer that the opposite case won't work, the answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @Jeremy: thanks your right *someone* Didn't read that and saw it on question when Matt Ball said _but i did say trailing_ ! LOLZ.

Comment: @Omeid: I think you must misread me. If I were any calmer, I'd be in a coma. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try defining a function like so:

```
function stripToNums(str) {
    return str.replace(/\D/g, '');
}
```

And call that on your strings.  It should strip any non-digit chars out of the string.  Of course, you'll need to get a little trickier if you want to handle non-integer number values.

Here's a live demo of that: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/QEhfR/

Note that you'll need to parse the returned strings as ints in this example, or the script will do string concatenation with the two returned values, rather than the intended mathematical addition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt()`. It returns an integer value.